# Comparing different samples from different years: ANOVA?

Tags: time-series, anova, likert, bonferroni, tukey-hsd-test

I have been collecting data for 10 consecutive years. Once in each year different participants (N=110/Year) had to rate the importance of each one of 30 different social values, on a Likert scale (1-5). What is the most appropriate method to look at the changes that have taken place year after year regarding these values? In other words, how can I explore whether the importance of each one of the social values have changed or not? (ANOVA - Bonferroni or Tukey? Correlation- Pearson? Does it make sense to use both methods?)

Comment: To start. maybe pick 1 of the 30 social values of particular interest. You will have 110 Likert scores on that 1 social value in each of 10 yrs. Do a one-way ANOVA with years as level of the factor. Then the overall F-test of the ANOVA will let you know if attitudes on that social value have changed signif over 10 years. If so, you can try various _ad hoc_ tests to see if the change was for one or two years, or whether the change was a steady trend across the 10 yrs. // I'm not saying to do 30 such ANOVAs, but after a few you may have a better idea what is really of interest in all these data.

Comment: I have already conducted a one-way ANOVA for the 30 values. 4 of them are significant. Ad hoc test shows the years where a change has taken place (for example 2008 and 2015 for the valueX, 2009 and 2019 for the value Y etc.). My question is whether ANOVA is the appropriate analysis for this data. I have tried also to check the correlations between YEAR (as a group) and the 30 values. Significance (Pearson) was detected for more values compared to ANOVA  (ANOVA shows significance for 4 values while PearsonCorrelation for 6 out of 30 values).